# matplotlib ticks not align with data point

Tags: matplotlib

I have modified [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794225/python-plot-stem-with-datetime-base) but it seems the x tick mark position not correct if set nbins=10! but it works fine if set nbins=5. what's wrong with me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
#%matplotlib inline
#-----------------------------------------#
def main():
    ticks = [ "9-28 11:07:57.435", "9-28 11:10:00.123", "9-28 11:40:00.654", "9-28 11:50:00.341", "9-28 12:00:00.773"]
    y = np.array([10, 12, 9, 15, 11])
    x = [mktime(datetime.strptime("2014-"+i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple()) for i in ticks]
    plt.stem(x,y)
    plt.xticks(x, ticks,rotation=25,ha='right')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=10, prune = 'lower'))
    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.gca().spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
    plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    plt.show()
    return

#-----------------------------------------#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: you are giving only 5 ticks, the problem is they are not recognized as datetime objects, use a proper index. The problem is in plt.xticks line of code

Comment: Yes, it's a string but you know stem function doesn't support datetime object, so I use this workaround.

Comment: Why are you setting the ticker to MaxNLocator after using xticks?  That line obliterates the tick locator xticks just set.  Notice that if you set nbins=5, it does *not* place the ticks where the stems are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `plt.xticks`, what it does is set the tick locator to a **FixedLocator**, allowing you to place the ticks explicitly.  When you then assign the tick locator to a **MaxNLocator**, you override the explicit tick placement.

To get a maximum of N ticks, you can pull N values from your ticks list and just pass those to xticks, and eliminate setting the locator manually.  These lines pull 3 ticks out of your current list of 5 as an example.

```
inds = np.linspace(0,len(ticks)-1,3).astype(int)
plt.xticks(np.array(x)[inds], np.array(ticks)[inds],rotation=25,ha='right')
```

Comment: Yes, but I wish to use it because I want it to display only 10 ticks if the ticks too many. so so many ticks case. so for many ticks case, the 10 bins is recalculated or just select 10 bins from it?

Comment: It looks like your data is not uniformly sampled, so if you pick out 10 points to place ticks at, they probably won't be evenly spaced.  Is that what you want, or do you just want evenly spaced ticks to show the correct dates?

Comment: What I want is: data align exactly the label, if number too bigger, just show 10 label but it should match the data also. I no need it distribute evenly.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with your suggestion. One defect is if the data point near each other, the labels will be overlapped.e.g. the first 2 ticks. how can we display only one ticks for such case?

Comment: @Beatlej you shouldn't keep changing your question - please keep the question what it was when it was answered, or it doesn't make any sense to other people.  If you have something more, ask another question

Answer (score 0):

One solution as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime

#-----------------------------------------#
def main():
    x = [
"9-28 11:07:57.435",
"9-28 11:10:00.123",
"9-28 11:40:00.654",
"9-28 11:50:00.341",
"9-28 12:00:00.773"
]
    y = np.array([10, 12, 9, 15, 11])
    dtlst = str2dt(x)
    plt.stem(dt2float(dtlst),y)
    bins = 5
    dtlst = list(linspace(dtlst[0],dtlst[-1],bins))
    plt.xticks(dt2float(dtlst),dt2str(dtlst),rotation=25,ha='right')
    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.gca().spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
    plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    plt.show()
    return

def str2dt(strlst):
    dtlst = [datetime.strptime("2014-"+i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in strlst]
    return dtlst

def dt2float(dtlst):
    floatlst = [mktime(dt.timetuple()) for dt in dtlst]
    return floatlst

def dt2str(dtlst):
    dtstr = [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z") for dt in dtlst]
    return dtstr

def float2dt(floatlst):
    dtlst = [datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds) for seconds in floatlst]
    return dtlst

def linspace(start, end, bins):
    delta = (end - start)/bins
    x = start
    while x <= end:
        yield x
        x = x + delta
    return

#-----------------------------------------#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
#-----------------------------------------#
```

Output:

[image]